# Homebrew permission denied on file I own with rwx permissions

Tags: macos, gcc, permissions, homebrew, macos-sierra

I have a 2016 MacBook Pro (w/ touchbar) and Mac OS Sierra (10.12.3). I freshly installed Homebrew (v1.1.9) and ran `brew install gcc49`. It appears to install all dependencies fine, but once it gets to gcc, I get

```
Error: Permission denied - /Users/<me>/Library/Caches/Homebrew/gcc@4.9-4.9.3.tar.bz2
```

Original permissions after downloaded by Homebrew:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 <me>  <company_domain>    86M Jun 26  2015 /Users/<me>/Library/Caches/Homebrew/gcc@4.9-4.9.3.tar.bz2
```

I tried setting to `755` and group to `admin`, but no luck:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <me>  admin    86M Jun 26  2015 /Users/<me>/Library/Caches/Homebrew/gcc@4.9-4.9.3.tar.bz2

> brew install gcc49
Updating Homebrew...
==> Using the sandbox
==> Downloading https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-4.9.3/gcc-4.9.3.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Users/<me>/Library/Caches/Homebrew/gcc@4.9-4.9.3.tar.bz2
Error: Permission denied - /Users/<me>/Library/Caches/Homebrew/gcc@4.9-4.9.3.tar.bz2
```

I then `chown`ed the directory to be group `admin` instead of the company domain. It already had `775` permissions. Still no luck.

I have seen several posts where people had to `chown` directories to make homebrew happy, but I don't see permission issues on the given file or directory.

`brew doctor` reports some unexpected dylibs, header, and `.pc` files. I'm not sure if those came from my company's Mac OS image.

Am I overlooking something obvious? I appreciate any help.

Here is the entire initial install output:

```
> brew install gcc49
==> Installing dependencies for gcc@4.9: gmp@4, mpfr@2, libmpc@0.8, isl@0.12, cloog
==> Installing gcc@4.9 dependency: gmp@4
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gmp@4-4.3.2.sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring gmp@4-4.3.2.sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

This is an alternate version of another formula.

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/gmp@4/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/gmp@4/include

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/gmp@4/4.3.2: 20 files, 2.4M
==> Installing gcc@4.9 dependency: mpfr@2
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/mpfr@2-2.4.2.sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring mpfr@2-2.4.2.sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

This is an alternate version of another formula.

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/mpfr@2/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/mpfr@2/include

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mpfr@2/2.4.2: 25 files, 2.7M
==> Installing gcc@4.9 dependency: libmpc@0.8
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/libmpc@0.8-0.8.1.sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring libmpc@0.8-0.8.1.sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

This is an alternate version of another formula.

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/libmpc@0.8/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/libmpc@0.8/include

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/libmpc@0.8/0.8.1: 12 files, 273.8K
==> Installing gcc@4.9 dependency: isl@0.12
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/isl@0.12-0.12.2.sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring isl@0.12-0.12.2.sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

This is an alternate version of another formula.

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/isl@0.12/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/isl@0.12/include

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/isl@0.12/0.12.2: 57 files, 2.9M
==> Installing gcc@4.9 dependency: cloog
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/cloog-0.18.4_1.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring cloog-0.18.4_1.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/cloog/0.18.4_1: 35 files, 442.4K
==> Installing gcc@4.9
==> Using the sandbox
==> Downloading https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-4.9.3/gcc-4.9.3.tar.bz2
==> Downloading from http://mirror.easthsia.com/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.9.3/gcc-4.9.3.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: Permission denied - /Users/<me>/Library/Caches/Homebrew/gcc@4.9-4.9.3.tar.bz2
```

Comment: Is `SIP` protection turned on or off? (from terminal `csrutil status`)

Comment: Bah, yes! Do I need to disable it permanently? Or should I? I'm not security savvy enough to know how much it helps.

Comment: I think you just need to disable it while you're installing anything to directories owned by root. Once you've installed whatever it is that needs to be there then it's probably safe to turn it back on.

Comment: Apparently Sierra requires you to disable it from Recovery Mode: `csrutil: failed to modify system integrity configuration. This tool needs to be executed from the Recovery OS.` I'm trying to find whether it's possible to 'unprotect' only homebrew-specific folders, but I'm not sure what all of those might be. Maybe it's not even possible?

Comment: Yeah, that is the standard way to disable/enable `SIP`, so it's sort of an inconvenience, especially if you plan on installing things often. There really isn't a way to unprotect individual directories as `SIP` is system-wide, and why you have to boot into recovery mode to disable it. If you're constantly installing things then really the only option is to have it disabled. When new OS updates come out it often re-enables itself. One other note, you probably don't have a `/usr/local/` directory (eg. if it's a fresh install), so you might need to create that directory also.

Comment: I just found a post where [Homebrew's lead maintainer states that disabling SIP 'is a bad idea.'](http://discourse.brew.sh/t/homebrew-time-machine-and-sip/444) I wonder what the recommended approach is...

Comment: I don't really see any other way around it unless you are jumping through hoops all the time. The maintainer said `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local` does the trick, so maybe try that. Personally I don't use `homebrew`, `MacPorts` is what I roll with, but everyone has their preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to sudo `chown -R <me>:admin /usr/local/*` and try again. You may need to restore some user or group ownership recursively (which this command will do).